# Appcelerator module with my own sqlite3 build

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, sqlite, appcelerator

I am writing an appcelerator module to use my own sqlite3 build. The problem that I am facing is that the default system sqlite code seems to get linked regardless.

I have tried a number of things, but I would have throught that placing all the sqlite code in my .m file would result in that code being called.

MySqlite.m

```
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "sqlite3.c"

#pragma Public APIs
-(NSString *)getSqliteVersion:(id)args
{    
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_libversion()];
}
```

The getSqliteVersion member still returns version number of the iOS standard sqlite library

So does anyone know how to alter the linker to pick up my own sqlite code or is there a way to "wrap" the sqlite in a namespace or such like?

EDIT 10/10/12:
Sorry, bit more info that is relevant. The build process is two steps.

The part I am doing is to build the module which is a packaged static library, i.e. a .a file

This .a file is distributed to other users and then they build their application with this module. So that is why I can't control the second linking step and remove any .dylib sqlite references.

Some how I think I need to get my sqlite lib into a private "namespace". I use namespace conceptually, I know C doesn't have them

Not sure if it helps, but the Ti build commands for the module build seem to be:

Build settings from command line:

```
SDKROOT = iphonesimulator5.0
```

=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET tisqlite_crypt_ios OF PROJECT tisqlite_crypt_ios WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies

```
CompileC build/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Release-iphonesimulator/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_iosModule.o Classes/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_iosModule.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-return-type -Wno-parentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -DTI_VERSION= -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000 -iquote /TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Release-iphonesimulator/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_ios-generated-files.hmap -I/TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Release-iphonesimulator/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_ios-own-target-headers.hmap -I/TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Release-iphonesimulator/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_ios-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Release-iphonesimulator/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_ios-project-headers.hmap -I/TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/include "-I/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.3.GA/iphone/include" "-I/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.3.GA/iphone/include/TiCore" -I/TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Release-iphonesimulator/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Release-iphonesimulator/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/DerivedSources -F/TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator -DTI_POST_1_2 -include /var/folders/LP/LPsQmql2FfCGO9YCrCUKUU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_ios_Prefix-hbaweqhgijjnfpfynapljpziqmjk/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_ios_Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Release-iphonesimulator/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_iosModule.d -c /TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/Classes/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_iosModule.m -o /TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Release-iphonesimulator/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_iosModule.o

In file included from /TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/Classes/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_iosModule.m:14:
/TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/Classes/sqlite3.c:27620:32:{27620:32-27620:45}{27620:30-27620:31}: warning: implicit conversion from 'long long' to 'long' changes value from 9223372036854775807 to -1 [-Wconstant-conversion,3]
     mask = (sizeof(long)==8) ? LARGEST_INT64 : 0x7fffffff;
                              ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/Classes/sqlite3.c:7946:25: note: instantiated from:
 #define LARGEST_INT64  (0xffffffff|(((i64)0x7fffffff)<<32))
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.

Libtool build/Release-iphonesimulator/libUkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_ios.a normal i386
    cd /TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only i386 -syslibroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator -filelist /TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Release-iphonesimulator/tisqlite_crypt_ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/UkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_ios.LinkFileList -ObjC -framework Foundation -o /TitaniumStudioWorkspace/tisqlite_crypt_ios/build/Release-iphonesimulator/libUkCoClinicalsoftwaresolutionsTisqlite_crypt_ios.a


** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```